# Design Pattern for parsing serial strings

Tags: design-patterns, string-parsing, micr

What design pattern do you suggest for the following case:

A class is needed to represent the serial string of some documents which consists of numeric characters. There are 4 types of serials and the first character of the string specifies the type of serial. Each type of the serial has some numeric fields that are separated by the pipe character. Serial types differ only in the number of fields that they have (which is fixed for each type). The meaning of each field is irrelevant and can have arbitrary values. A serial string ends with a pipe character that is followed by a two-digit checksum of all preceding numeric values of the serial. For example, the following string represents a type 2 serial number:

20202|5666|00020|31

Here, the first digit, 2, specifies that the serial is a type-2 serial. The serial string has 3 fields and the checksum of the serial is the last two digits, 31, which is simply the sum of all preceding numbers.

In this case, it is fairly easy to solve the problem without using any particular pattern but I'd like to know what famous patterns can be utilized to solve this problem or similar ones (for example, parsing MICR data of banknotes).

Comment: i thing about: fabric + strategy.

Comment: Both fabric and strategy patterns seems to be good ideas. It is a good idea to use the fabric pattern for creating Serial objects and to use the strategy for encapsulating the checksum algorithm for different serial types. Thanks @W92.

Answer (score 0):

As @W92 mentioned, using a factory to return a parsing strategy would be a common approach. A separate strategy encapsulates the parsing logic needed for each type.  A C# example...

```
 var serialNumber = "20202|5666|00020|31";
 var factory = new SerialParserFactory();
 var parser = factory.GetParser(serialNumber);
 IParsingResult result = parser.ParseSerial(serialNumber);
```

The parsers all implement a common interface with a single method, ParseSerial that returns a IParsingResult.  The parsers can be as simple or as complex as needed.

```
public interface ISerialParser
{
   IParsingResult ParseSerial(string serialNumber);
}

public class SerialParserType2: ISerialParser
    {
        public IParsingResult ParseSerial(string serialNumber)
        {
            string[] parts = serialNumber.Split("|".ToCharArray());

        int[] fields = new int[parts.Length-2];
        for (int partIndex = 0; partIndex < parts.Length-1; partIndex++)
        {
            int value = 0;
            if (!int.TryParse(parts[partIndex], out value))
            {
                value = 0;
            }
            fields[partIndex] = value;
        }
        int checkSum = 0;
        if (!int.TryParse(parts[parts.Length-1], out checkSum))
        {
            checkSum = 0;
        }
        return new Type2Result
        {
            Fields = fields,
            CheckSum = checkSum
        };
    }
}
```

Same with the results...

```
public class Type2Result: IParsingResult
{
    public int[] Fields { get; set; }
    public int CheckSum { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, the factory can be simple...

```
public class SerialParserFactory
{
    public ISerialParser GetParser(string serialNumber)
    {
        string typeChar = serialNumber.Substring(0, 1);
        switch (typeChar)
        {
            case "2":
                return new SerialParserType2();
        }
        return new NotFoundParser();
    }
}
```